# コメント欄の＠ユーザーについて

Tags: サポート, コメント

スタックオーバー初心者です。
コメント欄に@ユーザー名 様と入力してコメントを入れて投稿すると
@ユーザー名 が消えて、様から始まります。
なぜでしょうか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「@ユーザー名」と入れるのはそのユーザーに通知を送りたいからだと思いますが、「@ユーザー名」が無くても通知が飛ぶ場合、勝手に消えるようになっています。英語圏では「@ユーザー名」の後に「さん」とか「様」とかをつけないのでこの方式でもそこまで不便はありませんが、日本語だとたまに変な挙動に思えることがあります。

コメントは、通常2人のユーザーに通知を飛ばすことができます。1人はコメントした投稿の投稿者で、もう1人は「@ユーザー名」で指定したユーザーがいればそのユーザー、いなければそのコメントのすぐ上のコメントをしたユーザーです。

更に、「@ユーザー名」による指定をしなくても通知が飛ぶ場合、「@ユーザー名」が自動削除されるときがあります。典型的には質問へ最初にコメントする際、その質問の投稿者へ「@ユーザー名」しようとすると自動削除されます。

もっと詳しく: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/341401